# How to automatically generate a menu item when creating a K2 content?

Tags: joomla-k2

Is there a way to automatically generate a menu item when creating a K2 content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one and i'm totally happy with it! Work with  both normal joomla articles and k2 ones!

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/addtomenu

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're after but you could just use the K2 content module to display a 'menu' by overriding it and outputting an HTML unordered list?

Comment: ehm, I'm not sure I got what you mean! My purpose is to create a joomla menu item in the main menu that link to my content directly during the content creation. As it is now after creating a content you have to go to the joomla menu configuration and create it manually. I'm just looking for a faster way.

Comment: What I mean is that the K2 Content Module will display a list of K2 content items. You can override the template so that you just show the title (and link) in an underordered list. This way, any time you add a new K2 item, it will appear in the module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a K2 specific extension to do it, but it would be pretty simple to modify a Joomla Section/Category/Article based extension to work with K2.

This extension looks like it would be a good candidate- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/tree-menus/11452

The other option would be to fake a menu by using the K2 content module in a CSS styled list.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe try JLinker Mass Menu Link Generator: http://www.jlinker.com

It works with Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.x, it's free and it allows you to generate links for Joomla articles and categories. There are also extensions to generate links for K2 and Virtuemart.